# How to insert a new donation and associate an existing user with donation?

Tags: soap-api, php

I am using the PHP SOAP API and trying to insert a new user (or retrieve an existing) and then insert & attach a new donation, but there doesn't seem to exist a donation "standard object".  Is there something I'm missing from the API or is the Donation object (accessible on the frontend through the "Donations" tab) called something different through the API?

EDIT: Still no luck, this is a screen of the CONTACT -

[image]

- how do I lookup this information from the contact or from the opportunity (which is called Donations, I think)?

Comment: Is donation not a custom object, API name ending with "__c"?

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm misunderstanding how custom objects work. Where can I view details on what their API names are and how to query them/attach them?

Comment: From UI, Go to Setup-> App Setup -> Create -> Objects. This should list all the Custom objects in the Org. Click on Donations and should see a field called "API Name". You can use force.com explorer or force.com eclipse plug-in (among others) and write and run your queries.

Comment: Aha! Donations was simply a renamed tab of "Opportunity"! Thanks Sai. So I create an Opportunity with the Owner set to the ID of the new Contact?

Comment: Great, that's correct!!!

Comment: Actually, Sai, I still can't find where the heck I can set the associated Opportunity with the Contact. I've edited above to show a screenshot of what I mean. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are using the Nonprofit Starter Pack, which renames the label of the standard Opportunity object to Donations. You can determine for sure if you have the NPSP by going into the Setup menu and down to Installed Packages. There would be one or more packages like those listed here: http://nonprofitstarterpack.org/

The NPSP has two models for how individuals and donors are tracked in Salesforce, the 1-to-1 model and the bucket model. In the 1-to-1 model, each Contact would get a corresponding Account of the same name. In the bucket model, each contact that is not associated with a business account gets associated with a "bucket" account called Individual. 90% of nonprofits have the 1-to-1 model.

To associate an Opportunity (Donation) with a donor, in the 1-to-1 model, you will need to put the donor's account id into the AccountId field on Opportunity. If your settings are correct (Contacts and Organization Settings in all tabs) to auto-create contact roles, you will get your Opportunity Contact Role created automatically.  Alternatively (or if you are in the bucket model), you would put the Contact id into the Contact Id for Role field on Opp to create the contact role.

Comment: greenstork, thanks very much for the information! How do I know if I'm in the 1-1 model or the bucket model, is that configured? I'm taking over the site from another dev and trying to figure out the system. I updated the OP to show a screenshot of the donations.

Comment: You can also find that in the Contacts and Organizations Settings, under Account Model at the top of the settings page.

Comment: There are two great resources for you to learn more, beyond the nonprofitstarterpack.org site, there are two google groups, one called Nonprofit Salesforce Practitioners and one called Nonprofit Starter Pack.

Comment: Great, I'll investigate those groups right away.